Does lombok's "staticConstructor" apply to this situation?
I have a class that looks like this :
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter
public class MyClass {

    Integer mField1;
    String mField2;

    // No public constructor. You may NOT call (null, null) or (field1, field2)

    // Factory-like constructor, when there's only field1
    public static MyClass fromField1(@NotNull final Integer field1) {
        return new MyClass(field1, null);
    }

    // Factory-like constructor, when there's only field2
    public static MyClass fromField2(@NotNull final String field2) {
        return new MyClass(null, field2);
    }
}

Can I replace this :
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter

...with this :
@Value(...)

...and if yes, how?
I'm guessing staticConstructor is related to this use case, but I'm not 100% sure it fits the need. In my case:

I don't know how to do when there's more than one static constructor-like method.
I have a feeling that staticConstructor can only generate a static constructor with all the parameters. I don't want to expose that. I literally only want those two static "constructors" that are already here.


As far as I understand the documentation on @Value this will create a public all-args constructor. You could, however, add @Builder to have it generate a private one and also add the builder itself. That being said is there a specific reason for using those factory methods other than providing default values for the fields that aren't specified by the method?

@Thomas The reason is that the object can have only one of the two values, but neither none of them nor both of them . I CANNOT expose any constructor or static constructor that would let the end consumer of the class call with (null, null) or (field1, field2)

This feels like you might want to reevaluate your design, e.g. instead of having a class with 2 mutually exclusive properties why not have 2 separate classes with a common interface or base class? If you really need to use one class I'd probably try using @Value and @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) together and then just write the factory methods myself (btw the term "static constructor" would not be appropriate and can be misleading - those static methods are called "factory methods").

Another note on the factory methods: if the 2 options are basically just different ways to construct the same object (e.g. passing a number as a number or a string which then is parsed) I'd put those differences into the factory methods only and keep the instance data as simple as possible (which also simplifies implementation of other methods and may improve performance). As an example you might have MyClass fromNumber(Integer n) { return new MyClass(n); } and MyClass fromString(String s) { return MyClass(Integer.parseInt(s)); }.

@Thomas while I appreciate the advice on good OOP design, I'm working with legacy code. I can use lombok to make the code more compact, but I cannot fundamentally change the design and introduce polymorphism and a set of new classes.  In conclusion : I don't think I can use the "staticConstructor" keyword here

Well, I didn't mention using staticConstructor (a term which is wrong anyway)  - did you check my other comment on using @Value and @AllArgsConstructor?

@Thomas yes that second part of your comment comes to the same conclusion as the answer I posted myself. If you write an answer I will mark it down as the accepted answer. You may copy-paste my own answer as it is pretty thorough.

No, that's fine. I won't steal your answer :)

No, "staticConstructor" does not apply to this situation.
The goal is to generate this, in pseudo Vanilla Java :
class MyClass {
   private MyClass(param1, param2) {} // <-- PRIVATE

   // absolutely no way of having both values null or both not null.
   public static MyClass ofParam1(param1) { return new MyClass(param1, null); }
   public static MyClass ofParam2(param2) { return new MyClass(null, param2); }
}

If I do this:
@Value(staticConstructor = "of")
then I get
class MyClass {
   private MyClass(param1, param2) {}

   // I don't want this method
   public static MyClass of(param1, param2) { return new MyClass(param1, param2); }
   
   public static MyClass ofParam1(param1) { return new MyClass(param1, null); }
   public static MyClass ofParam2(param2) { return new MyClass(null, param2); }
}

If I do this:
@Value(staticConstructor = "ofParam1")
then I get
class MyClass {
   private MyClass(param1, param2) {}

   // I don't want this method
   public static MyClass ofParam1(param1, param2) { return new MyClass(param1, param2); }
   
   public static MyClass ofParam1(param1) { return new MyClass(param1, null); }
   public static MyClass ofParam2(param2) { return new MyClass(null, param2); }
}

The best I can do is this :
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)

In conclusion, the best possible code reduction is only to replace @FieldDefaults+@Getter with @Value:
(using the code from the question)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Value
public class MyClass {

    Integer mField1;
    String mField2;

    // No public constructor. You may NOT call (null, null) or (field1, field2)

    // Factory-like constructor, when there's only field1
    public static MyClass fromField1(@NotNull final Integer field1) {
        return new MyClass(field1, null);
    }

    // Factory-like constructor, when there's only field2
    public static MyClass fromField2(@NotNull final String field2) {
        return new MyClass(null, field2);
    }
}

